# Find the value of the limit $\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{\log a_n}{\log n}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, analysis

Consider all natural numbers whose decimal expansion has only the even digits $0,2,4,6,8$. Suppose these are arranged in increasing order. If $a_n$ denotes the $n$-th number in this sequence then the value of the limit: $\displaystyle \lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{\log a_n}{\log n}=$

(a) $0$.

(b) $\log_5 10$

(c) $\log_210$

(d) $2$

I observe that the sequence $\{a_n\}=\{2,4,6,8,20,22,24,26,28,40,42,44,46,48,60,62,64,68,80,82,84,86,88,200,202,204,206,208,\cdots\}$.

I am not getting the explicit formula for $a_n$, but it shows that the growth is exponential. How to find the exact value of the limit ?

Also I found that $a_n \ge n$ always, from which we get the required limit is $\ge 1$. So option (a) is incorrect.

Any hint. please

Comment: https://www.quora.com/Consider-all-natural-numbers-whose-decimal-expansion-has-only-the-even-digits-0-2-4-6-8-Suppose-these-are-arranged-in-increasing-order-If-a-n-denotes-the-n-th-number-of-this-sequence-then-what-is-the-value-of-lim_-n

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that limit actually exists, take $n=5^k$ then $a_n= 2\times10^{k}$ for all $k\in\mathbb{N}$.
$$\displaystyle \lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{\log a_n}{\log n}=\lim_{5^k\to \infty}\frac{\log (2\times10^{k})}{\log 5^k}=\lim_{5^k\to \infty}{\log_{5^k} (2\times10^{k})}=\log_510$$

Comment: This is fine for a multiple choice test, since it shows that the right answer can only be b).  However, a little bit more is required to show that the limit actually exists.  This is easy, but it should be mentioned.

Comment: @saulspatz Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: @Asher2211 How do you get the last limit ?

Comment: @Empty $\displaystyle\lim_{5^k\to \infty}{\log_{5^k} (2\times10^{k})}=\lim_{5^k\to \infty}\log_{5^k} (2)+\lim_{5^k\to \infty}\log_{5^k} (10^{k})=0+\log_510$

Answer (score 1):

Through some basic counting, there are $4\cdot 5^{i-1}$ such $i$ digit numbers. Hence, when $$\sum_1^k 4\cdot 5^{i-1} \lt n \le \sum_1^{k+1} 4\cdot 5^{i-1} \iff 5^k-1 \lt n \le 5^{k+1} -1,$$ it must be that $$10^k \le a_n \lt 10^{k+1} $$ These two inequalities give $$\frac{k\ln 10}{\ln(5^{k+1} -1)} \le \frac{\ln a_n}{\ln n} \lt \frac{(k+1)\ln 10}{\ln(5^k-1)} $$ Taking the limit as $k\to \infty$, the middle part is squeezed to $\frac{\ln 10}{\ln 5} = \log_5 10$.